# PrimeFaces p:fileUpload multiple files autoComplete only works after first file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I try to upload some files then redirect to another page by `oncomplete` 
the problem is that `oncomplete` is only working just after the first file is uploaded

```
<p:fileUpload  mode="advanced"
     label="#{FileMessages.file_add_file_lbl_Select_File}"
     fileUploadListener="#{fileAddFileAction.upload}"
     oncomplete="redirect(#{fileAddFileAction.groupId});"
     multiple="true"
     allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|doc|docx|pdf)$/"
     widgetVar="fileUplaod" >
 </p:fileUpload>
```

Java Script function: redirect(groupId)

```
function redirect(groupId) {
     var url = "/network/group/files.html?gId="+groupId;
     $(location).attr('href',url);
}
```

bean.java

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {

    UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();

    try {
        String thumbnail = getDestination() + uploadedFile.getFileName();
        String[] filetype = thumbnail.split("\\.");
        String newfilename = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + "." + filetype[1];

        SystemFile file = new SystemFile();
        file.setAccount(getActor().getAccount());
        file.setCtime(new Date());
        file.setName(newfilename);
        file.setPath(getDestination());
        file.setFileType(FileUtil.checkFileType(filetype[1]));
        file.setOriginalName(uploadedFile.getFileName());

        getFileService().saveSystemFile(file);

        copyFile(getDestination() + newfilename, uploadedFile.getInputstream());

        copyFile(getDestination() + newfilename, uploadedFile.getInputstream());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileAddFileAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a known issue : http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3836

A custom patch has been done by a user on this page :

> It can be used by adding the following line inside a p:fileUpload tag:

```
<p:ajax event="fileUploadsComplete" listener="#{filesBean.done}"/>
```

> where the filesBean.done methode looks like this:

```
public void done(FileUploadsCompleteEvent event) {
    System.out.println("done"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (Primefaces 5). Adding an ajax fileUploadsComplete failed due to a 'Parent not an instance of ClientBehaviorHolder' error.

Here is my hack-around. It's not the most satisfying but it's working:

```
<script>
    function setUploadFilesCount() {
        var numberOfFiles = $('.ui-fileupload-preview').size();
        var input = document.getElementById('fileupload-multi-fix-input');
        input.value = numberOfFiles;
        input.onchange();
    }
</script>

<h:form id="file-upload-form">
    <p:fileUpload id="file-upload" fileUploadListener="#{backingBean.handleFilesUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
                               sizeLimit="10000000" multiple="true" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpg)$/" onstart="setUploadFilesCount()" update=":content">
    </p:fileUpload>
</h:form>

<h:form prependId="false" style="display:none;">
    <h:inputText id="fileupload-multi-fix-input" value="#{backingBean.numberOfUploadFiles}">
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form"  />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
```

So in my BackingBean I have the following:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int numberOfUploadFiles; //... add getter and setter

    private boolean isUploadComplete = false; //... add getter and setter

    private int uploadCount = 0;

    public void handleFilesUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {

        // ... handle file upload here

        uploadCount++;

        if(uploadCount == numberOfUploadFiles){
            isUploadComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

I added a JavaScript function  `setUploadFilesCount` and a second `<h:form />` containing a hidden `<h:input />`.

`<p:fileUpload onstart=...` is called once at the beginning of the (first) file transfer. 
I call the JavaScript function `setUploadFilesCount` in `onstart` to set the number of upload files in my backing bean.

The number of files  is detected by reading the number of occurrences of an element with the css class `ui-fileupload-preview`. The number of `ui-fileupload-preview` elements in the view equates the number of upload files. This happens in

```
$('.ui-fileupload-preview').size();
```

`input.onchange();` causes the hidden input field value to be submitted to the backing bean.

On the backing bean I can check if the last item was uploaded by incrementing a counter

```
uploadCount++;

if(uploadCount == numberOfUploadFiles){...}
```

So I can check if all items are uploaded or call a special function after the last upload item is finished.

---

`<p:fileUpload oncomplete...` is called everytime one of the upload files is uploaded.

So in your particular case you would have to additionally wrap your javascript in something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="afterLoad">
    <h:outputScript>
        function redirect(groupId) {
            if(#{backingBean.isUploadComplete}=='true'){
                var url = "/network/group/files.html?gId="+groupId;
                $(location).attr('href',url);
            }
        }
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

put it in the same form as the `<p:fileUpload` and add `<p:fileUpload ... update="afterLoad" ...`